# Generating "terasort" input data set with TeraGen

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to generate a data set (for my own "terasort" MapReduce job) by running the [TeraGen program](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/TeraGen.html) that ships with Hadoop (inside *hadoop-examples.jar*):

```
hadoop jar /<full-path>/lib/hue/apps/oozie/examples/lib/hadoop-examples.jar teragen 1000 ./teragen
```

I am not getting the expected output that should follow the format:

```
(10 bytes key) (10 bytes rowid) (78 bytes filler) \r \n
```

I am getting a file that:

- starts with `JimGrayRIP` followed by a `NUL` character (when I am trying to paste it, it gets truncated; [I uploaded a copy to Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88038/stackoverflow/teragen-results.zip)),
- contains two characters repeated every 100 bytes, but - instead of `OD OA` - they are `EE FF`.

What can be wrong?
Can this be any encoding issue?

Is a sample "terasort" data set available for download anywhere?

Comment: Please post the command you are trying for generating input using teragen utility

Comment: @h4ck3r I have just updated my question.

Comment: This is a pretty stupid way to pay tribute to anyone.  It completely messes up the format.  This is holding up real work.

Comment: Do you mean the first key? Well, that's not my choice. Teragen works like: https://mobile.twitter.com/fs111/status/373420714746839040